# Will applications in the software center receive updates of new versions?

Tags: 11.10, software-center, application-development

Is it possible to provide updates for software in Ubuntu 11.10 software center.
For example upcoming versions of vlc, inkscape and many others.

Comment: Are you asking if you can provide the updates manually? or if updates will be provided to you for applications?

Comment: I want to know, if there will be updates for software from the offical repositories. Like software updates in other app stores.

Answer (score 0):

New versions of applications can be provided after they have made it into the development release by [backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports). This repository is enabled by default in 11.10, but it is not an automatic update for packages that you have installed.

Backports are built & tested mainly by volunteers, and there are some limitations on what updates can be provided, depending on how many other packages depend on them.

Answer (score -1):

I know that Firefox will have version updates, like it has now in 11.04, but other software won't. Only bugfixes will be provided.
You need to install other ppas like now.

Answer (score -1):

The GetDeb project provides new updates for open source and freeware applications. This is an easy way to get new sofware into Ubuntu. [GetDeb.net](http://www.getdeb.net)

But software updates should be a core feature of the Ubuntu software center. A small notification could show you if updates are available and ask you to install. It would be nice if someone could mention this on the right place for development.