# Does programs installed through software-center get updated?

Tags: software-center, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will applications in the software center receive updates of new versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64912/will-applications-in-the-software-center-receive-updates-of-new-versions)

Is "every and all" installed applications/programs once installed through Ubuntu Software Center are monitored and routinely updated through the Ubuntu (specifically, the Update Manager) on a Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit operating system? Or are there "a few exceptions" to this where there may be the case where some circumstances of applications/programs installed through Software Center may NOT be updated through Ubuntu (specifically, the Update Manager)?

Please explain. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the general policy is that once Ubuntu is released, the software version is locked down.  The software is patched for various reasons, over time, but not necessarily improved upon, until the next release of Ubuntu.

There are exceptions.

A notable exception is if you add the developer's software repository to your software manager's list of software sources.  In that scenario, you can grab updates the second the developer makes them available... for better or worse.

**Edit**:

No, there will not be automatic updates of software installed from the Ubuntu Software Center.  If updates are available, you can choose to install the updates if you want.

Comment: @ E-man: Hello. Nice ot meet you. Thank you for your comment. I was wondering more along the lines of every install directly from the Ubuntu Software Center ALWAYS means there will be automatic updates for those installed programs or not? Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: To add to what E-man has said, each software in the USC has a mention of whether Canonical will support it  or not and for how long. For example: "Canonical does not provide updates for console-based network traffic monitor. Some updates may be provided by the Ubuntu community." One more point, if you approve of E-man's answer, you can **accept** it. That's the way to show your approval.

Comment: Who edited my original question? Why was it edited? I do not appreciate that at all!!! The way my question reads now does NOT have the same meaning as it originally did!!! Not very happy here if users are going to change my words!!!

Comment: I didn't edit it.  You can see question revisions @ http://askubuntu.com/posts/123885/revisions